# Can not build Xamarin's ModernHttp version

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I noticed ModernHttp is not being updated long time,
After search some, I noticed there is Xamarin updated version.

here.
https://github.com/xamarin/ModernHttpClient

I want to try this. 
But I couldn't find it on nuGet Gallery nor build library to my own. 
It gives error "obsolete api" when I try build android library. 
Can't understand because I set API level as library use.

> Android/OkHttpNetworkHandler.cs(273,48): error CS0619:
>   `System.Net.ServicePointManager.ClientCipherSuitesCallback' is
>
>   obsolete:`This API is no longer supported.'
>         Task "Csc" execution -- FAILED
>         Done building target "CoreCompile" in project "/Users/bright/Devlibs/project/untitled folder/ModernHttpClient2 copy 
>   3/src/ModernHttpClient/ModernHttpClient.Android.csproj".-- FAILED
>             Done building project "/Users/bright/Devlibs/project/untitled folder/ModernHttpClient2 copy
>   3/src/ModernHttpClient/ModernHttpClient.Android.csproj".-- FAILED
>          Build FAILED.    Errors:

Any tip please?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this link : 
https://components.xamarin.com/view/modernhttpclient

Visual studies and Xamarin studios should have an easy way to add in components. 
This link can help with learning about there usage : 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-studio/components_walkthrough/

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is this Xamarin's updated version as I wrote in question?